# managing dynamic database connection with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am new in symfony, i want to manage multiple dynamic database connection

Wath i do:
when user register on my symfony app, i create new doctrine config for him, with new connection and new entity manager.
this step work fine; but
after this, i want to use my new configs for create database and update schema using these configs.

when i do it, symfony tells there is no new_manager and new_connection found

please can some body help me ?

my code

```
private function create_configs(Request $request, KernelInterface $kernel){
        $port = $request->get('_db_port');
        $host = $request->get('_db_host');


        //getting template
        $file = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../../../config/packages/customers_config/template/doctrine_template.txt");

        //setting config connection
        $file = str_replace("CUSTOMER_DB_CONNECTION","une_co",$file);
        //setting config url
        $file = str_replace("CUSTOMER_DB_URL","mysql://". $request->get('_username').":". $request->get('_userpassword')."@".$host.":".$port."/bdod?serverVersion=5.7",$file);
        //setting config manager
        $file = str_replace("CUSTOMER_EM","managerf",$file);

        //saving config
        $fp = fopen(__DIR__ . "/../../../config/packages/customers_config/some_config.yaml","wb");

        fwrite($fp,$file);

        fclose($fp);

        return $this->create_database($kernel, "une_co", "managerf");

    }


    private function create_database(KernelInterface $kernel, $connection, $manager){
        $dir = __DIR__."../../../";

        (new Filesystem)->remove(__DIR__."../../../var/");

        $cmd_string = "php". $dir."bin/console";

        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $cache  = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'doctrine:cache:clear-metadata',
        ]);

        $create = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'doctrine:database:create',
            '--connection' => $connection,
            '-n' => true,
            '--no-debug' => true,
        ]);

        $schema = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',
            '--force' => true,
            '--em' => $manager
        ]);

        // You can use NullOutput() if you don't need the output
        $output = new BufferedOutput();

        try {
            $application->run($cache, $output);
            $application->run($create, $output);
            $application->run($schema, $output);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }

        // return the output, don't use if you used NullOutput()
        $content = $output->fetch();

        // return new Response(""), if you used NullOutput()
        return new Response($content);
    }
```

Comment: Please use parameterised queries for your SQL statements, not by composing your own strings. This is a very bad habit, as it leads to SQL Injection and apparently random failures of your queries depending on the input values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Symfony, you should use Symfony's tools to simplify things.

[Doctrine with Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Comment: i use Symfony 4.4. and there is a bug in Doctrine. then if you do something like $customers = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Customer::class, 'customer')
            ->findAll();

Comment: Thanks, there was a problem with Doctrine, when i call repositories's method from any entity manager, Doctrine uses a first entity manager in the list, i solve it by changing this entity manager before calling repository.
for those who have the same problem, overwrite the repository constructor.
for exemple :

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry){
      parent::__construct($registry, Agency::class);
      $this->_em = EntityManagerController::getEntityManager();
    }

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by deleting cache after adding new configs. but not with Doctrine command, i deleted them with custom php code